# how do i inherit/overwrite a forced style from a windows theme?

Tags: wpf, inheritance, themes, styles

currently i am forcing my WPF app to use the luna theme no matter what, with this XAML code

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="NavigationCommands.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/RibbonControlsLibrary;component/Themes/Office2007Blue.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Luna, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;;component/Themes/luna.normalcolor.xaml" /> 
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

and now i want to extend the style of every textbox with this validation trigger

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#d3e1f3"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                   Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

but this trigger does not work, because i forced the luna theme. (without the forced theme every thing works as it should, but doesn't look as it should :( )
is there some way to force the luna theme and extend it's style? probably over the BasedOn property?

atm i defined a key for the style in question and added it to every textbox by hand, that works but isn't the prettiest way to go.

tia

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
```

Answer (score 1):

The BasedOn syntax for type styles is as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
```

HTH

Comment: no luck :(
the approach over the basedon property does not work. the style gets ignored.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the lune resourcedictionary first and your own resourcedictionary last?
I can imagine the luna theme overrides your style.

```
<Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Luna, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;;component/Themes/luna.normalcolor.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/RibbonControlsLibrary;component/Themes/Office2007Blue.xaml"/> 
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="NavigationCommands.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the mentioned

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
```

but also make sure your dictionaries are included in right order - first the ones you are basing your style on

```
<Application.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/RibbonControlsLibrary;component/Themes/Office2007Blue.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Luna, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;;component/Themes/luna.normalcolor.xaml" /> 

        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="NavigationCommands.xaml" />
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```